# Unable to create Hyper-V VM on SMB share

Tags: windows-server-2012, hyper-v, server-message-block, failovercluster

I'm trying to create a VM on Hyper-V 2012 R2 server and I'm getting this error:

```
The server encountered an error while creating VMNAME
The Operation failed
Failed to create external configuration store at "\\SMB\Server\Path": General access denied error. (0x80070005)
```

This is a brand new cluster, using SMB share to store VM disks and config files etc. All servers are Server 2012 R2 and all updates are done.

I was able to create a VM before (a few hours before, where no setting have been touched at all), but I'm getting that error for some reason I can't explain.

I tried gpupdate /force, logged out/in. Followed a few KB that might help with no success.

There is no access/permission problem for the account being used as the account can create/delete folders on the SMB share.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you create the VM on the node you're creating it from. I've seen if you are on NODE-A and attempt to create a VM on NODE-B, you'll get this error.